# Accessing params from ajax modal

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

In my rails app I have an index controller method which has the bucket_id stored in the url params like this: `http://localhost:3000/posts?bucket_id=3` When I call `params` it returns `{"bucket_id"=>"3", "action"=>"index", "controller"=>"posts"}`

On this page, I also have a button that opens an ajax modal to the new path of the same controller.  When I call `params` here, it returns `{"action"=>"new", "controller"=>"posts"}` and I'm not able to access the bucket_id.  Although the browser URL still says `http://localhost:3000/posts?bucket_id=3`

I can't seem to figure out how to pass the params from the index method to the new method when I click to open the ajax modal.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Do you pass the `bucket_id=3` in ajax call?

Comment: Is the modal HTML on the index page? If so how about passing the id as a data-attribute on the modal?

Comment: Pass it like `new_post_path(:bucket_id => params[:bucket_id])` from the button inside `index` method call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Abhi 's  solution worked for me as I was using the rails link_to helper:

`<%= link_to '', new_post_path(:bucket_id => params[:bucket_id]), remote: true, id: 'js-topbar-add' %>`

and I was able to access the bucket_id in the modal by simply calling `params[:bucket_id]`

Thanks!